# Access Low and High fields and keeping fields blank in a form

Tags: sql, xcode, forms, ms-access

First off I had the problem of if I wanted to keep a field blank on my form and only search on another field (Such as if you had 2 fields but I only wanted to search the database for one, and keeping the other blank) it would come back with the right results.

I did this by using: Like [Forms]![BackUpValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO] & "*"
in all of the fields on my form and just changing the textbox area to the new textbox.  This worked like a charm.

But now My new question is I need to keep that functionality and also allow for a range.

I have an access link that is to a server table. The table has a column that has a low number and then a separate column that has a high number. For example, the low could be 100 and the high could be 200. This means that any account that falls in between those 2 numbers pass the test of this table. So If I had an account that had an account number of 101 and I put that in my form and click the run button it should bring back any row that has both fields as 101 (so low and high is both 101, meaning this is the only account that this rule applies to) and any other row that has say low of 100 and high of 200 because its in between both of those. I have a few columns like this, account low and high, function low and high.

Basically with just using the criteria that I started with (Like [Forms]![BackUpValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO] & "*") it would not capture those records that have a range that may be under it and then above it meaning its in the middle some where.

I have tried: Between [ACCOUNT_CD] And [ACCOUNT_CD_HIGH] and it works by itself.  But if I put that same thing in the other field that is on this form too and I leave that field blank and I just search for account in the form it will bring back no results.

I've tried the following:

Like "*" And Between [ACCOUNT_CD] And [ACCOUNT_CD_HIGH] & "*" and also tried Between [ACCOUNT_CD] And [ACCOUNT_CD_HIGH] & "*" and for the other field the same things in conjunction with each other and neither will produce data together

Also Tried: 
 Like [Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO] & "*" And Between [ACCOUNT_CD] And [ACCOUNT_CD_HIGH]
 with the same thing in the other form field:
 Like [Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![FunctionR3CMBO] & "*" And Between [OP_TYP] And [OP_TYP_HIGH]

And also tried putting an "Or" in between them instead of an "And"

Anyone know how I can fix this?

My Actual Access SQL:

```
SELECT VALIDATION_RULE3.ACCOUNT_CD, VALIDATION_RULE3.ACCOUNT_CD_HIGH,
Rule3_Accounts.Description, Rule3_Accounts.D0_DESCA, Rule3_Accounts.D0_TYPE, 
Rule3_Accounts.D0_PARENT, Rule3_Accounts.D0_WEIGHT, Rule3_Accounts.D0_LEVEL,
Rule3_Accounts.D0_CHILD, Rule3_Accounts.D0_PRIORITY, Rule3_Accounts.D0_STATUS,
Rule3_Accounts.D0_CHILDSORT, Rule3_Accounts.D0_CREATE, Rule3_Accounts.D0_MODIFY, 
Rule3_Accounts.D0_BALTYPE, Rule3_Accounts.AccountText, VALIDATION_RULE3.XPN_OP_TYP_CD

FROM Rule3_Accounts INNER JOIN O8_VALIDATION_RULE3 ON Rule3_Accounts.AccountText = O8_VALIDATION_RULE3.ACCOUNT_CD

WHERE ((([Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO]) Like [Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO] & "*" Or ([Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO]) Between [ACCOUNT_CD] And [ACCOUNT_CD_HIGH] & "*")
AND (([Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![FunctionR3CMBO]) Like 
[Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![FunctionR3CMBO] & "*" 
Or ([Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![FunctionR3CMBO]) Between [XPN_OP_TYP_CD] And [XPN_OP_TYP_CD_HIGH] & "*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to check if the parameter is blank or not.

```
Where (isnull(@account_cd) or field1 >= @account_cd)
and     (isnull(@account_cd_high) or field1 <= @account_cd_high)
```

This will return true if the parameters have been left null (you might need to do `@account_cd = ''` instead depending on how your code is written). Then, if the parameters are not null, then whatever column you are comparing them to should be checked against the value. Since you don't know if both values will be supplied or if just one will, between is just not going to work for you.

Also, sql short circuits, so if the values of your parameters are null, the second part of the `or` will not be checked. This is why it is extremely important to do the null check first when encountering these types of problems.

Comment: Here's my Access SQL thus far: WHERE ((([Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO]) Like [Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO] & "*" Or ([Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO]) Between [ACCOUNT_CD] And [ACCOUNT_CD_HIGH] & "*") AND (([Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![FunctionR3CMBO]) Like [Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![FunctionR3CMBO] & "*" Or ([Forms]![ValidationForm1_3]![FunctionR3CMBO]) Between [XPN_OP_TYP_CD] And [XPN_OP_TYP_CD_HIGH] & "*"));  Also I have made each field in the form be "" instead of null on the form which makes Like [Forms]![BackUpValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO] & "*" work

Comment: But now I need it to continue working even if a field is blank and also find records that are also in between the low and high columns

Comment: @user3456880 I don't think what you wrote and what I wrote are the same things, but to be honest I can't tell because your code is extremely difficult to read. It would help if you included the whole query instead of just the where clauses and formatted it as a code block. I believe the sql that I entered in my answer will work if a field is blank and will find the records specified.

Comment: I tried to clean up the code a bit.  I don't think what you were originally was talking about would help in this situation.  In the textboxes in the form I have default value as 2 double quotes like this "" so that it wont search for null values and these databases have no null values in them.  I need it to allow me to keep a field blank in the form, which I originally fixed by doing Like [Forms]![BackUpValidationForm1_3]![AccountCMBO] & "*" but now I need it to continue to do that and also look at the low and high columns to see if it is between those numbers if it is, include it aswel